# Get a value from a dictionary key in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

The code below will print out the auction information that I need however I would like to be able to just print out one item value (e.g itemType , rating).

```
page = requests.get('https://utas.s2.fut.ea.com/ut/game/fifa16/transfermarket?num=16&leag=13&type=player&start=0&lev=silver&maxb=200', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
mydict  = page.json()
print mydict['auctionInfo']
```

This will output the following json. How can I just extract one value ?

```
[{u'sellerEstablished': 0, u'itemData': {u'rating': 69, u'itemType': u'player', u'resourceId': -2147297053, u'cardsubtypeid': 2, u'morale': 50, u'lifetimeAssists': 1, u'id': 241577723458, u'statsList': [{u'index': 0, u'value': 8}, {u'index': 1, u'value': 0}, {u'index': 2, u'value': 0}, {u'index': 3, u'value': 0}, {u'index': 4, u'value': 0}], u'assetId': 186595, u'teamid': 1792, u'pile': 5, u'suspension': 0, u'rareflag': 0, u'playStyle': 250, u'attributeList': [{u'index': 0, u'value': 82}, {u'index': 1, u'value': 64}, {u'index': 2, u'value': 67}, {u'index': 3, u'value': 69}, {u'index': 4, u'value': 48}, {u'index': 5, u'value': 57}], u'loyaltyBonus': 0, u'timestamp': 1443317273, u'training': 0, u'nation': 82, u'assists': 1, u'formation': u'f433', u'lifetimeStats': [{u'index': 0, u'value': 8}, {u'index': 1, u'value': 0}, {u'index': 2, u'value': 0}, {u'index': 3, u'value': 0}, {u'index': 4, u'value': 0}], u'leagueId': 13, u'untradeable': False, u'discardValue': 104, u'owners': 3, u'injuryGames': 0, u'contract': 10, u'injuryType': u'leg', u'lastSalePrice': 800, u'fitness': 75, u'itemState': u'forSale', u'preferredPosition': u'RM'}, u'tradeId': 159824505381, u'confidenceValue': 100, u'sellerName': u'FIFA UT', u'expires': 3581, u'buyNowPrice': 200, u'tradeOwner': False, u'offers': 0, u'startingBid': 150, u'watched': None, u'currentBid': 0, u'tradeState': u'active', u'bidState': u'none', u'sellerId': 0}]
```

Comment: Which value are you looking for?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget tradeId is the value I need

Comment: @Martin: `mydict['auctionInfo']['tradeId']`.

Comment: Next time, you can use [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) to examine structure of the object.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Thanks , I will take that on board!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by the `json` call is a nested dictionary. You just need to index each level to get your desired items. Since the top level of the `auctionInfo` value is a one-element list, you'll need to use `[0]` to get at its actual contents:

```
print mydict['auctionInfo'][0]['itemData']['itemType']
print mydict['auctionInfo'][0]['itemData']['rating']
print mydict['auctionInfo'][0]['tradeId']
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
print mydict['auctionInfo']['tradeId']
```

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
for i in range(len(mydict)):
try:
    for key, value in mydict[i].items():
        if key == "tradeId":
            print value
except:
    pass
```

You can change "tradeId" with any key to find its value

Comment: This solution is overkill.

Comment: But it works! And I think its more versatile! Anyway, for just the solution I admit the other answers are better